# Syntax::sntxf: "..." cannot be followed by ".....\MatrixForm"

Tags: matrix, syntax, warning-messages, vector

I'm trying to create a $3\times 1$ matrix named `Pauli` but I really don't understand what's the problem of the following code?

```
pauli = (1/Sqrt[2])*{{Shh + Svv}, {Shh - Svv}, {2 Shv}} \\ MatrixForm
Syntax::sntxf: "pauli=" cannot be followed by "(1/Sqrt[2])*{{Shh+Svv},{Shh-Svv},{2Shv}}\MatrixForm".
```

Comment: Use `//` not \\. And probably you want to do `pauli = stuff; stuff // MatrixForm` so that you don't define `pauli` with `MatrixForm` as its head. (It's these kinds of things that make it a problem that you want to use Mathematica as only a glorified graphing calculator. In order not to run into so many issues and errors, you need to understand the basic syntax and at least some of the basic logic of MMA. Also: if you run into problems like this: highlight the problem \\ , click F1 to take you to the help pages: there you will find out that it's is not defined. This is good practice!)

Comment: Alternatively, use `(pauli = (1/Sqrt[2])*{{Shh + Svv}, {Shh - Svv}, {2 Shv}} )// MatrixForm` this will assign the matrix correctly (without the unwanted MatrixForm head), but it will still pretty-print the result as a nicely formatted matrix. In general, you should never use any of the *Form function in assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Use forward slashes, not backslashes. That is, replace `\\` with `//`.